# How do I use mypy to annotate a numpy array containing a custom dtype?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mypy, dtype

I have a custom numpy dtype that will be used in numpy arrays. How should I annotate the array variable in a function declaration in order to capture the type constraint? I'm guessing I need to better annotate the dtype declaration itself, but am not sure how.

As an example, please consider this script:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

MY_DTYPE = np.dtype([("major", "u2"), ("minor", "u2"), ("patch", "u2")])
my_array = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], dtype=MY_DTYPE)


def print_entries(array_var: npt.NDArray[MY_DTYPE]) -> None:  # <- mypy gets angry here
    """Print array entries."""
    for row in array_var:
        print(row)
```

`mypy` gets angry at the `npt.NDArray[MY_DTYPE]` and points me to the [variables vs. type aliases](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases) section of the common mistakes. But the `TypeAlias` and `Type` annotations don't seem to be solving the problem.  How do I annotate this?

Thanks much for your help!

Comment: That's a compound dtype used to create a `structured` array.  I haven't used `typing` much, but am not surprised that it can't handle such a dtype.  If anything you need to study `numpy's` own typing extension looking for structured array.

Comment: Explore `npt.DTypeLike` - https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.DTypeLike

Comment: type and dtype are not the same thing.